# Change color and appearance of drop down arrow

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I want to change the default appearance of the arrow of a dropdown list so that looks the same across browsers. Is there a way to override the default look and feel of the drop down arrow using CSS or otherwise ?

Answer (score 64):

You can acheive this with CSS but you are not techinically changing the arrow itself.

In this example I am actually hiding the default arrow and displaying my own arrow instead.

```css
.styleSelect select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 168px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  color: #000;
}

.styleSelect {
  width: 140px;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("images/downArrow.png") no-repeat right #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="styleSelect">
  <select class="units">
    <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
    <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
    <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, however there are two problems:  1. in IE8 a blue background after selection is over the arrow image,  2. in Opera the arrow image is not visible. :(

Comment: This was more intended to be a guide rather than me completing all the work for OP

Comment: @Sphvn: Nice Answer, I have added  `-moz-appearance: none` & `appearance: none` to your solution to handle most browsers.

Answer (score 21):

No, cross-browser form custimization is very hard if not impossible to get it right for all browsers. If you really care about the appearance of those widgets you should use a javascript implementation.

see http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200409/styling_form_controls/
and http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example07.html

Answer (score 20):

It can be done by:

```
select{
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat 100% 50%;
}
```

```css
select{
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat 100% 50%;
  
  
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    appearance: none;
    outline-width: 0;
    
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
  }
```

```html
<div class="styleSelect">
  <select class="units">
    <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
    <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
    <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: how would you customize the color with this method?

Comment: use different background svg.

Comment: how did you get the svg data? @Lambder

Comment: @karinapichardo https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/

Comment: sweet, thank you @Lambder , also for anyone wondering the same, I found this really helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218307/select-arrow-style-change

Answer (score 3):

The `<select>` element is generated by the application and styling is not part of the CSS/HTML spec.

You would have to fake it with your own DIV and overlay it on top of the existing one, or build your own control emulating the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily done I am afraid. The problem is Css cannot replace the arrow in a select as this is rendered by the browser. But you can build a new control from div and input elements and Javascript to perform the same function as the select.

Try looking at some of the autocomplete plugins for Jquery for example.

Otherwise there is some info on the select element here:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Style-Sheets/Taming-the-Select/

Answer (score 1):

We have used YUI, Chosen, and are currently using the jQuery Select2 plugin: https://select2.github.io/

It's pretty robust, the arrow is just the tip of the iceberg.

As soon as stylized selects becomes a requirement, I agree with the others, go with a plugin. Don't kill yourself reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it by using an actual `<select>`, but there are techniques that allow you to "replace" them with javascript solutions that look better.

Here's a good article on the topic: [<select> Something New](http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/)

Answer (score -1):

Unless you plan on creating your own drop down list (and not using a standard library drop down list), you are stuck. The DDL control's look is going to be based upon the system you are running and/or the browser that is rendering the output.

Answer (score -1):

Just change background-image property with css.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing the color of your "border-top" attribute to white