# Setting the select dropdown arrow color (workaround for a bug in Chrome 36.0.1...)?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

In the current version of Chrome 36.0.1... there's an annoying bug where the dropdown arrow is always black, making it useless if it's in a container with a quite dark background.

The select element's color attribute isn't applied either (though it works on the text of the closed element itself), nor is the inherited color. My searches always came up either useless or with tutorials to replace the whole thing, but that would be overkill.

Since there's a ton of legacy selectors still present to style elements like the scrollbar, is there also one to just define the color of the arrow without having to replace everything but the damn kitchen sink?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: take a look at this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow)

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly my point. I just want to fix the color, not replace the whole thing because of one little arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to change the default select menus without completely overriding them.  The individual browsers all render forms differently, and this is a known pain-in-the-ass.