# How to change color drop down list selector

Tags: html, css

[image]

**How to change the color drop down selector list.**

*design Issue.*

Answer (score 0):

I think it's using [triangle](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) you can change border colors in css. or generate a triangle using [triangle](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/). I suggest you to read [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) first.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this with CSS but you are not techinically changing the arrow itself.

In this example I am actually hiding the default arrow and displaying my own arrow instead.

HTML:

```
<div class="styleSelect">
  <select class="units">
    <option value="Metres">Metres</option>
    <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
    <option value="Fathoms">Fathoms</option>
  </select>
</div>




.styleSelect select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 168px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #000;
}

.styleSelect {
  width: 140px;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("images/downArrow.png") no-repeat right #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: This is same as the answer in the given question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow