# -Webkit-appearance: menulist, color change

Tags: html, css, webkit-appearance

Can you change the color of the arrow (menulist).
       I'm not able to change the color of it, can anyone help me with this?

HTML

```
 <select class="drop_down_menu">
 <option>Yolanda van der Kamp</option>
 <option>Bernard Vogels</option>
 <option>Stefan Janssen</option>
 <option>Maik de Boer</option>
 </select>
```

CSS

```
.drop_down_menu{
background-color:#eaeaea;
border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
color:#104c64;
-webkit-appearance:menulist;
}
```

Comment: We need to see your existing HTML & CSS.

Comment: done that now @Paulie_D

Comment: If you want to change the dropdown arrow you will need to hide and replace it with your own e.g. an image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, with css appearance. Mind that IE doesn't support appearance in which case you will need to get hacky.

```
.drop_down_menu{
appearance:listbox; //mind browser-specific properties;
}
.drow_down_menu:before{
content : "\someglyph"; //add glyph or image as background;
position:absolute; //and wherever you want to place it.
}
```

And now to get hacky for the IE just create a wrapper around the select and then set select with

```
width:120%;
```