# How to make submenu act like dropdown but show first value like select

Tags: jquery, css

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ADEX</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-page">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#two">Programmes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">Info</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#four">Travel</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-nav"></div>
 </div>
</nav>
<nav class="submenu">
  <div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-justified">
    <li>
      <ul class="nav nav-justified collapse" id="one">
           <li class="active"><a href="#">2015</a></li>
           <li class="active"><a href="#">About Mission</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="nav nav-justified collapse" id="two">
         <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="nav nav-justified collapse" id="three">
         <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul class="nav nav-justified collapse" id="four">
        <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.submenu{
  background: #404040;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 67px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.nav-justified > li > a{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.collapsing {
  display:none;
}

.nav-justified .active:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f9f9f9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-justified > li > a:hover,
.nav-justified > li > a:focus{
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-brand{
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .navbar-brand{
    display: block;
  }
}

.navbar{
  background: #F1F1F1!important;
  border: 0!important;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a{
  color: #000!important;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
 }
}

.navbar-nav > li:hover > a{
  border-top: 7px solid #0083A0;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #0083A0;
  padding-top: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 23px;
}

.nav-page > li > a{
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-page > li{
  padding: 30px 15px;
}

.nav-page > li:hover{
  padding: 0 15px }
```

Jquery

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $('.collapse').not(this).removeClass('in');
  });

  $('[data-toggle=collapse]').click(function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle=collapse]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
       var text = $(this).text();
    $('.navbar-brand').html(text);
  });
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamlex/8uon0g4g/)

[image: Screenshot example]

Unable to make submenu dropdown with collapse to close and expand to open.

Screenshot showed one main nav with the list and submenu dropdown will automatically "populate" the submenu list from the main nav. The first will show 'A' in the dropdown menu and then it will enable the users to click arrow down to see the full submenu list under Programmes for example.

1. How to make submenu as similar as dropdown select?
2. How to make submenu display first text? For example, submenu list has A, B, C, D. So it should show A first. then user clicks on arrow down to see more submenu list - A B C D.

Any help appreciated.

[image: Show you better example of what I am looking for]

This is the example of what I am looking for.

Main navigation should be in its own bar and submenu navigation should be in its own bar whether desktop or mobile.

Then on mobile screen, submenu navigation should be acting as dropdown. It will show the list of the selected list from main navigation

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gulfarazyasin/8uon0g4g/2/)

I've changed the hierarchy so that the `sub-menu` is aligned properly to the main-menu. Without the hierarchy change the alignment would be impossible with pure CSS.

I used some JavaScript for the toggle until I figured out `data-toggle`. So no JavaScript ^.^

I used a `select` tag for the drop down, which works just fine but cannot be customized. There is a workaround to change the arrow. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow) post for the instructions.

My changes to your fiddle are as follows

CSS:

```
div.sub_menu {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    min-width: 100%;
}

div.sub_menu.in {
    display: block;
}

div.sub_menu > select {
    background: #404040!important;
    min-width: 100%;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-page">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
     </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">About</a>
        <div class="sub_menu nav nav-justified collapse" id="one">
            <select>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="Mission">Mission</option>
            <option value="History">History</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#two">Programmes</a>
        <div class="sub_menu nav nav-justified collapse" id="two">
            <select>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">Info</a>
        <div class="sub_menu nav nav-justified collapse" id="three">
            <select>
            <option value="E">E</option>
            <option value="F">F</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#four">Travel</a>
        <div class="sub_menu nav nav-justified collapse" id="four">
            <select>
            <option value="G">G</option>
            <option value="H">H</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for your help....I am sorry but it is not what I wanted. As I mentioned, the main navigation and submenu will be on each bar. And on mobile screen, they have to be in their own bar, in other words the main navigation and submenu are outside of each other.