# Styling select option arrows

Tags: html, css

Are there any ways to get arrows in Firefox like this:

[image]

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

HTML:

```
<select id="state" name="user_state">
                <option value="new_york">New York</option>
                <option value="california">California</option>
                <option value="florida">Florida</option>
                <option value="texas">Texas</option>
                <option value="hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="washington">Washington</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color and appearance of drop down arrow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.selectWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background:#FFFFFF url('data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2211%22%20height%3D%2211%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2011%2011%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M4.33%208.5L0%201L8.66%201z%22%20fill%3D%22%2300AEA9%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E') right 13px center no-repeat;
}

.selectWrapper select {
    padding: 12px 40px 12px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<br><br><br>Pure css solution: <br><br><br>

<div class="selectWrapper">
    <select>
        <option>Lorem</option>
        <option>Parturient</option>
        <option>Euismod</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <label class="select">
    <select name="email" id="email">
        <option>x</option>
        <option>y</option>
        <option>z</option>
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        <option>c</option>
    </select>
</label>

.select {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 40px;    
    width: 240px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

select{       
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 16px;       
    width: 240px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
.select:after {
    content:"\f0dc";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: #000;
    padding: 12px 8px;
    position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;      
    pointer-events: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;   
}
```

Look at the [codepan](http://codepen.io/eraditya123/pen/JKZOxB) in mozilla

Comment: Now this will look same in mozilla as well as chrome same