# How to change the position of a drop down arrow in CSS

Tags: html, css, dropdown

**NOT A DUPLICATE-please read carefully and understand the question.I don't want to replace the arrow. I want to keep the arrow as the way it is and change it's position. `appearance:none` can hide the arrow and by setting `background:url()` I may be able to replace the arrow,but that's not my question**

I have a dropdown list which appears good and works fine. We all know by default it adds a dropdown arrow at the right side of the dropdown list.Now what I want to do is to move the arrow bit lower to the position like `margin-top:5px`. But I can't find any `pseudo elements` or `classes` to write my code. I want to achieve this using only **css**. I found styles written to hide the element and add another one, but in my case I want to keep the icon as the way it is and change the position.

html

```
<select class="dropdown-select">
   <option value="">Select Location</option>
   <option value="location-1">Location 1</option>
   <option value="location-2">Location 2</option>
   <option value="location-3">Location 3</option>
</select>
```

css

```
.dropdown-select{
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: @halfer Sorry sir

Comment: No apology needed Ramesh, just adding some advice for your future questions! Proposals of duplicate questions are in fact _helpful_, and many a time I have seem them solve the problem at hand.

Comment: The duplicate register on this is about positioning a custom arrow. Not the default.It's poor form to falsely flag things as duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not ideal to do it this way regardless. The `<select>` element particularly is hard to style. I would recommend changing the appearance instead via `appearance: none;`

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow) is a good place to start.

Comment: Is there no other way? instead of replacing the arrow ,set the position as I wanted

Comment: I am afraid not. That's just how they are designed to work. You're better off changing the appearance to suit your needs.

Answer (score 36):

Checkout how bootstrap is doing it [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/e8f4cba9a05fc06fc6f7f11883b9c82e2027bff0/scss/forms/_form-select.scss#L17). in summary, they hide the original with `appearance: none` and add a custom SVG icon  using `background-image` property

Answer (score 1):

this code select custom appearence,what is your problem:

```
<select class="white_select select_category">
   <option value="">Select Location</option>
   <option value="location-1">Location 1</option>
   <option value="location-2">Location 2</option>
   <option value="location-3">Location 3</option>
</select>

.white_select {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1) url(../../../assets/images/down-arrow.png) no-repeat scroll calc(5% + 3px) center/8px auto;
    width: 100%;
} 

.select_category {
    font-size: 9px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 6px 4px;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url(../../../assets/images/down-arrow.png) no-repeat scroll calc(5% + 3px) center/8px auto;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    color: #939598;
}
```

Comment: It's even the same. I want to keep the arrow as the way it is. Your answers is like to replace the icon. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Change position of custom arrow in select options.

```
background: url(../images/downarrow.png) 97% center no-repeat !important;
```

Comment: Seems the same. Are there no option to keep the arrow as the way it is and change the position?

Comment: @Ramesh, it will work when you will use down arrow image to replace exiting down arrow.

Comment: Yeah I changed the code and it worked. Thank you for your time and answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no special pseudo elements for select dropdown icon in css.

But you can change the position of the icon by background property.

Or else use this kind of "height" or "line-height" for good look.

```css
.select_category{
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding:0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<select class="white_select select_category">
   <option value="">Select Location</option>
   <option value="location-1">Location 1</option>
   <option value="location-2">Location 2</option>
   <option value="location-3">Location 3</option>
</select>
```