# How can you change this arrow's position so that it is more inclined to the left?

Tags: html, css

I want to change this black arrow inside a selector from the initial position. How would you do that with CSS?

```css
.form-control-countrySelector {
  height: 40px;
  width: 421px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 30px;
  /* white */
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid rgba(60, 66, 87, 0.12);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.005em;
  font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
  color: #1A1F36;
  padding: 9px;
  margin-left: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select className="form-control-countrySelector">
    <option>United States</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" className="form-control-countryZIP" id="cardNumber" placeholder="ZIP" />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any arrows on Microsoft Edge Version 95.0.1020.53 (Official build) (64-bit) on Windows 11. There's the normal downward-facing carat that all `select`s have, but no arrows.

Comment: If you are talking about that carat, see [Change color and appearance of drop down arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/611482/215552), among many others.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide arrow than add `appearance: none;` attribute in **Select**

```css
select
{
      width:100px;
      appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>        
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want add arrow before the option than

Add background image :

```css
select{
    width:100px;
    appearance: none;
    padding:5px 2px 2px 30px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") no-repeat left center;
   
}
```

```html
<select>
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>        
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clip-path` property to draw your arrow and move it anywhere you want with `display: grid` and `justify-self` properties.
For example, you can put it in **center**.

```css
.select {
  display: grid;
   grid-template-areas: "select";
   align-items: center;
   width:50%;
}

.select::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.5em;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 0%, 50% 100%);
  justify-self: center;
  margin-right:5px;
}

select {
  /* A reset of styles, including removing the default dropdown arrow */
  appearance: none;
  /* Additional resets for further consistency */
  background-color: transparent; 
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  cursor: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

select,
.select:after {
  grid-area: select;
}
```

```html
<label for="standard-select">Select You Option</label>
<div class="select">
  <select id="standard-select">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="Option length">
      Option that has too long of a value to fit
    </option>
  </select>
```

Or put it in **left** side

```css
.select {
  display: grid;
   grid-template-areas: "select";
   align-items: center;
   width:30%;
}

.select::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.5em;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 0%, 50% 100%);
  justify-self: start;
  margin-left:5px;
}

select {
  /*A reset of styles, including removing the default dropdown arrow*/
  appearance: none;
  /* Additional resets for further consistency */
  background-color: transparent; 
  padding: 0 1em 0 1.2rem;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  cursor: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}
select,
.select:after {
  grid-area: select;
}
```

```html
  <label for="standard-select">Select Your Option</label>
<div class="select">
  <select id="standard-select">
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="Option length">
      Option that has too long of a value to fit
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

For more information, you can read [Custom Select Styles with Pure CSS](https://moderncss.dev/custom-select-styles-with-pure-css/) and [Awesome CSS Select Styles You Can Use Right Now](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/resources/css-select-styles/) articles.