# how to adjust the position of arrow down icon of the select element?

Tags: html, css

I can't adjust the position of the drop-down arrow icon in the select element of HTML, I want to adjust the icon so it's not that close to the right

an image is attached below.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUr11.png)

Comment: Kindly also add what you have already tried to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You cant move/style the arrow in select statement. You can remove the arrow by using style `appearance: none;`

More help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow).

Answer (score 1):

```
In this example, I am hiding the default arrow and displaying my own arrow.      

  <div class="abc">
        <select>
        <option value="a" selected="">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    
    <style>
        select{
            appearance: textfield;
            -webkit-appearance: textfield;
        }
        .abc {
            position: relative;
        }
        .abc:after {
            content: "";
            background: #ffffff;
            right: 10px;
            width: 24px;
            height: 23px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 999;
            background-image: url(arrow image path);
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            top: 11px;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Please do not just show code as an answer but give a description of what it has added in order to solve the problem so readers can gain understanding.

Comment: Ok sir I will try to add more details in my next answer.

Comment: Thans, you can edit this answer to add some description of what's going on too.